# css - Position scrollbar to give space to containing element (outside, not inside)

Tags: css, scrollbar

I'm just playing around with some css and created an element that scrolls and is displayed as a "porthole" kind of view. However, the scrollbar is covering a bit of the element.

I tried padding, margin and wrapping it in another div but can't quite get the result I was hoping for. I also tried applying the same border-radius and dimensions to a wrapping div and applying padding to that, but then the content goes outside of the inner div.

This will make it much more clear: http://jsfiddle.net/c78e3/1/

Current css:

```
div.two {
    margin:20px;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border-radius:150px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    background:url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/giphymedia/media/v0YiARQxj1yc8/giphy.gif') top center no-repeat;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    float:right;
    -webkit-shape-outside:circle(150px at 50% 50%) border-box;
    shape-outside:circle(150px at 50% 50%) border-box;
    -webkit-shape-margin:20px;
    shape-margin:20px;
    }
```

So is there a way to push it away from the scrollable content?

I guess what I'm trying to do, is make the scrollbar appear outside of the element rather than inside.

**UPDATE**
After answer was applied: http://jsfiddle.net/c78e3/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) - [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/c78e3/2/) on jsFiddle. Look at advanced demo to see how external scrollbar works and how to use it in your case.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('div.two').scrollbar();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was a lot of help. End result: http://jsfiddle.net/c78e3/5/